# Xpath-filtering, trying to filter on text contains

Tags: xpath

I am using Xpath to filter Windows Event Logs using PowerShells Get-WinEvent (this question is not restricted to PowerShell, but rather is an XPath question)

My input data (example event) as as follows

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-    4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4662</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>14080</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-08-14T09:03:17.496928900Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>787185775</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1220" ThreadID="6908" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyComputer.MyDomain.Local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-21-3674026133-984544165-2712361304-107629</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">svc-X</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">GROUP</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x35e0ae72d</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectServer">DS</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectType">%{19195a5b-6da0-11d0-afd3-00c04fd930c9}</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectName">%{38f2636c-4bec-4029-aab6-a2ce69751d1a}</Data> 
  <Data Name="OperationType">Object Access</Data> 
  <Data Name="HandleId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="AccessList">%%7688</Data> 
  <Data Name="AccessMask">0x100</Data> 
  <Data Name="Properties">%%7688 {1131f6aa-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2} {19195a5b-6da0-11d0-afd3-00c04fd930c9}</Data> 
  <Data Name="AdditionalInfo">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="AdditionalInfo2" /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Now if I save the following XPath statement to the variable $XpathQuery

```
$XpathQuery = "*[System[(EventID=4624)] and EventData[(Data`enter code here`[@Name='Properties'] )]]"
```

and run using the PowerShell Get-WinEvent cmdlet as follows

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -ComputerName MyComputer.MyDomain.Local  -FilterXPath  $XpathQuery
```

I get the output I would expect e.g. I get all 4624 events where EventData has an attribute named Properties

I want to fine tune my XPath query to only select entries where the **Properties** element **contains** the **text** 1131f6aa-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2 as there my be a few hundred entries where only a handful contain 1131f6aa-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2

Comment: The Xpath statement above did not come out correctly, reposting it below (hopefully it will come out OK this time.

Comment: Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -ComputerName BOVNDS001 -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID=4662)] and EventData[(Data[@Name='Properties'])]]"